Using dev containers with multi-root workspaces
I'm aware of existing requests like this: Multiple container support for multi root workspaces
But I want something much simpler.
I have a structure like this:
monorepo/
  monorepo.code-workspace
  backend/
    .devcontainer/
      Dockerfile
      devcontainer.json
  frontend/
    .devcontainer/
      Dockerfile
      devcontainer.json

Is there anyway to have the user prompted to choose which devcontainer to use when opening the multi-root workspace?
I don't need every workspace opened in its own dev container I want users to be able to add their own .devcontainer/ configs under their own folder in the mono-repo and choose that dev container config to open the workspace.
Also, I don't want to put all of my .devcontainer/ configs in a single top level folder. The point of this is that they live in their own folders and are managed there. I don't want to separate out the configs to some different folder for every single subfolder.

For what it's worth, I made a symlink to solve essentially the same problem:
cd monorepo/
ln -s backend/.devcontainer

Reloading the Window like that causes VS Code to pick whichever devcontainer I link to.
